# linux-image-3.19.-.26-generic broken

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus

For reference, I'm on Xubuntu Vivid, installed on a ASUS E451LD (aka a PL451LD). It has an Intel/Nvidia Optimus GPU setup.

- If I boot off a 3.19.0-26.28 kernel, it sticks on a blank screen or on the slash screen.  No reinstallation of any GPU-related packages works.
- If I boot off a 3.19.0-25.26 kernel, it boots nicely, no problems, even Steam works great.

I'm seeing (via a Google search) that 3.19.0-26.28 is a lemon of an upgraded kernel.  I've downgraded to the older package so at least I can use it.

How can I get 3.19.0-26.28 to work?

Comment: Is there a reason you want the newer version?